# Optimise Gear-VR text rendering with Unity

Tags: unity, gui, virtual-reality

I have a problem with my text being always kind of broken, so there are just some parts of the text visible (parts of letters) and the text flickers a lot.

At the moment I have this text 2D-UI text inside a canvas. Are there some optimisation techniques to resolve this issue, or are these glasses just not made for such "fine" lines? And no, it's not extremely tiny text and this does not happen in such an extreme way, when I display the text as an imported image.

Sorry for the lack of images, but I don't know how to capture an image from the app since I can't open the Oculus menu.

Update:
I figured out, that at a particular font-size, the flickering decreases a lot. I will investigate further on that.

Update:
Actually there is a particular font size, which is fine and everything larger works fine too. So I think you have to deal with pretty large font-sizes to prevent the text from flickering.